# Word macro for reversing selected text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to write a script that rearranges selected lines wherein the first line becomes the last line.

Sample Input:

Hello World.
My Name is Tom.
I'm maybe older than you.
maybe not.

Sample Output:

maybe not.
I'm maybe older than you.
My Name is Tom.
Hello World.

This is what ChatGPT created for me, but unfortunately it doesn't quite work:

```
Sub ReverseLines()
    Dim SelectionRange As Range
    Dim Text As String
    Dim ReversedText As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'Check if text is selected
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        MsgBox "Please select the text you want to reverse.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Save the selected text
    Set SelectionRange = Selection.Range
    Text = SelectionRange.Text
    
    'Reverse the selected text
    ReversedText = ""
    For i = Len(Text) To 1 Step -1
        ReversedText = ReversedText & Mid(Text, i, 1)
    Next i
    
    'Replace selection with reversed text
    SelectionRange.Text = ReversedText
End Sub
```

I tried searching in Google and ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to look for paragraphs and not manipulate the whole text.

```
Sub ReverseLines()
'Dim SelectionRange As Range
'Dim Text As String
Dim ReversedText As String
Dim i As Integer

'Check if text is selected
If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
    MsgBox "Please select the text you want to reverse.", vbExclamation
    
    Exit Sub
End If

'Save the selected text
'Set SelectionRange = Selection.Range
'Text = SelectionRange.Text

'Reverse the selected text
ReversedText = ""
For i = Selection.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
    ReversedText = ReversedText & Selection.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
Next i
```